# $injector:unpr angularjs when injecting a service in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble with injecting my service in angular that gives me $injector:unpr error. Here is my code:

```
(function () {

/**
 * This is a service to perform the backend REST calls for a Release
 */

'use strict';

angular.module('app.services')
        .service('ReleaseService', ReleaseService);
ReleaseService.$inject = ['$http'];
function ReleaseService () {

    var releaseService = {};

    var releasesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/releases';

    releaseService.releases = getReleases;

    return releaseService;  // return the release service object to the controller

    /**
     * Get the list of the releases. Does an HTTP GET request to the backend
     * @returns {Array} of releases to the caller of the service
     */
    function getReleases(){
        var releases = [];
        $http.get(releasesUrl).then(function(responseData){

            //check the status from the response data.
            if(responseData.status !== 200){
                alert('The request could not be completed. Please try again');
            } else{
                // else, Parse the json data here and return to the service caller
                for(var release in responseData.data){
                    releases.push({slug: release, data: responseData.data[release]});
                }
            }
        });
        return releases; 
    }
```

// This is the controller.js file where I inject the service I created above

```
(function (){

angular.module('app.uploadedReleases')
        .controller('UploadedReleasesController', UploadedReleasesController)
        .controller('ModalController', ModalController);


UploadedReleasesController.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', '$modal', 'ReleaseService', 'TrackService'];
function UploadedReleasesController ($log, $scope, $modal, releaseService, TrackService){

function init(){

        var something = releaseService.releases();
  }
}
```

Any idea what am I possibly missing ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue or contributing to the issue, but you are using `$http` in your service and you have not injected it. You injected it into your controller, but I don't think you need it there since you're not directly using `$http` in your controller. Also, where is your main app being registered? Make sure you are injecting both `app.services` and `app.uploadReleases`.

Comment: @Lex Good point about injecting $http in my service. I added it. And the app.services and app.uploadedReleases are registered in my main app. Let me update the code in the questions

Comment: `ReleaseService` is missing `$http`

Comment: @DanielA.White added and updated my question. Same problem exists

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the inputs folks. I think I was missing the registering the app.services in my main app module. Doing this solved the problem.